# requireJS: definining class to be used as global variable

Tags: jquery, require, requirejs

I really can't seem to grok RequireJS for some reason (having looked at various other questions)

Some background:

- I'm using jquery (so no Node.js automatic build stuff)
- I'm using a client-side mVC lib library (spine.js) which as part of it's setup, in my case, does `require("Avail")` deep inside it's code.
- 'Avail' is a javascript-class which is present globally as window.Avail

I'm getting the error-msg

`Uncaught Error: Module name 'Avail' has not been loaded yet for context: _
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded`

I get that it isn't loaded but how to do that? Is there a way to tell requireJS to register 'Avail' under the default context "_" when my app starts up?

I've tried several things like below (and lots of variations on that but I can't get it to work):

```
    (function() {   
       define("Avail", [],function(){
           return window.Avail
       });
     })();
```

Help much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that even though Spine.js in it's code already did a require on 'models/Avail', I had to do a require myself on 'models/Avail' as well.

### file: spine.models.coffee

```
class Avail extends Spine.Model
@configure 'Avail'

define "models/Avail", ->
  Avail
```

### file: main.html

```
  require(["jquery","models/Avail"], function($) {
    $(function() {
       new Spine.App();
    })
  });
```